# Ckeditor with jQuery form wizard

Tags: javascript, grails, ckeditor, wysiwyg, formwizard

I am creating a jQuery wizard based form(form is splitted in 5 steps) [wizard form](http://thecodemine.org/#), in last two steps I put two ckeditor respectively.My problem is that these two ckeditors are not responding i.e they dont accept any input.I am unable to figure out  why this happens.the same ckeditor works fine without form wizard.I think there is conflict between form wizard plugin and ckeditor plugin but dont know what exactly happens there.

**Sample project on github** [Link of grails project](https://github.com/manishkbharti/ckeditorformwizard).

Edit1:

This is my custom setting:

```
<div class="form-content">
    <div class="wizard-ignore">
<script type="text/javascript">
<ckeditor:config var="toolbar_Mytoolbar">
[
    [ 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Scayt' ]
]
</ckeditor:config>

delete CKEDITOR.instances['${name}'];
CKEDITOR.config.scayt_autoStartup = true;
CKEDITOR.config.fillEmptyBlocks = false;
function CKupdate() {
    for (instance in CKEDITOR.instances) {
        CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();
    }
}
<ckeditor:editor name="${name}" height="100px" width="98%" toolbar="Mytoolbar">
<g:if test="${summary}">
    ${summary}
</g:if>
</ckeditor:editor>

</script>
</div>
</div>
```

When I put some **alert(); statement** in above script ckeditor works in firefox.unable to find root cause.Any suggestion/idea will be helpful to me.

Edit2: 
Sample project on github [Link of grails project](https://github.com/manishkbharti/ckeditorformwizard).

Comment: Have you checked javascript erros in the console?

Comment: I am using firebug, but it does not shows any javascript error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Jan Sundman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/604562/jan-sundman) answer is absolutily correct just add class `wizard-ignore` to the editor.

---

You are using [grails CKEditor plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/ckeditor), you can set class as

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#${name}").addClass('wizard-ignore');

    <ckeditor:config var="toolbar_Mytoolbar">
    [
        [ 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Scayt' ]
    ]
    </ckeditor:config>

    delete CKEDITOR.instances['${name}'];
    CKEDITOR.config.scayt_autoStartup = true;
    CKEDITOR.config.fillEmptyBlocks = false;

    function CKupdate() {
        for (instance in CKEDITOR.instances) {
            CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();
        }
    }
});
</script>
<ckeditor:editor name="${name}" height="100px" width="98%" toolbar="Mytoolbar">
  <g:if test="${summary}">
    ${summary}
  </g:if>
</ckeditor:editor>
```

---

and if you use ckeditor directly as described in the [link](http://www.craigburke.com/post/55525089803/ckeditor-in-grails) then just add class as

```
<g:textArea name="foo" class="wysiwyg wizard-ignore">
```

Answer (score 3):

Set the class wizard-ignore to the editor, see if that helps.

Comment: I have added class wizard-ignore on the div in which ckeditor is placed but it did not change anything.