# Kendo upload is duplicating the first file

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-upload

I have a kendo upload with default implementation.

```
@Html.Kendo().Upload().Name("imageUpload").Multiple(true).Events(e => e.Select("selectFile"))
```

the first file I select to upload is getting duplicated I tested this on all browsers
[image: duplicated file]
I set the select event to this js function

```
function selectFile() {
        console.log(this.element[0]);
    }
```

the result was this:
[image: duplicated file console]
As I mentioned this happens only to the first file the rest will go normally
any idea why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't mention I'm using jQuery-Steps plugin because I didn't think it would be related.
apparently there is a conflict between some controls and jQuery-steps.
I needed to initialize the steps after kendo control is initialized
I found the answer here:
[jquery-steps-plugins-conflict-with-ckeditor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23506967/jquery-steps-plugins-conflict-with-ckeditor-rte-plugins/23522673?noredirect=1#comment36096991_23522673)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and turned out that

`@Html.Kendo().DeferredScripts()`

was accidently duplicated

Comment: Yea based on the symptom one thing or another is duplicated. For me I was setting the `localization` to set the Select text in the `$(document).ready` which essentially initializing the Upload control twice